# Difference between two datetime formats in android?

Tags: android, datetime-format, android-datepicker

As i am new to android development I am unable to find code for calculating the difference between two datetime formats. My question is.

I am using webservice in my project where i am getting datetime response as follows..

```
 starttime  :- [2012-11-04 10:00:00]
 endtime    :- [2012-11-04 12:00:00]
```

Here i want to display on screen as

```
   Today Timings  :-  2012-11-04   2 hours
```

Means need to calculate the difference between two dates and need to display the time difference on screen.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Are you trying to get time and date difference both? or just time?

Comment: I just want time difference and need to display starttime as i mentioned above.. in this pattern "Today Timings  :-  2012-11-04   2 hours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you know the exact format in which you are getting the date-time object, you could use the [SimpleDateFormat class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in Android which allows you to parse a string as a date given the format of the date expressed in the string. For your question:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date startTime = sdf.parse(<startTime/endTime String>, 0);
```

Similarly parse your endtime, and then the difference can be obtained using getTime() of the individual objects.

```
long diff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()
```

Then it's as simple as converting the difference to hours using:

```
int hours = (int)(diff/(60*60*1000));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks dude, solved the issue. Here other thing which i want is as per my question i need to seperate date from startTime string & need to display as like this "2012-11-04   2 hours". So, how can i do that..?

Comment: Ah sorry missed that part I guess. Use the substring method of Java to get the string containing your Date string. The docs have this method as String `substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`
So for `starttime  :- [2012-11-04 10:00:00]` this would be something like `timeString = inputString.substring(15, inputString.length());`.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2012-11-04 10:00:00", dtf);
        LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2012-11-04 12:00:00", dtf);
        long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(startTime, endTime);
        System.out.println(hours);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `java.util.Date;` you're gonna have to use an intermediate variable. you can convert your dates to `long` values and subtract those and then convert your long back to a date.

```
    long diff = new Date().getTime() - new Date(milliseconds).getTime();
    Date dateDiff = new Date(diff);
```

But you should be warned that it doesn't take daylight savings and whatever else variables into account. if you're that scrupulous, you might be indulged with this [replacement date class.](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) It has the functionality you seek.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get difference of two date.

```
public void getTimeDifference(Date endDate,Date startDate) {
            Date diff = new Date(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            calendar.setTime(diff);
            int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            }
        }
```