# is their any inbuilt method to check the difference between two dateTime in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to get the following output in android:

```
val oldTime = timeStoredInSharedPreference() // format : DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS
val newTime = currentTime() // format : DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS

val output = newTime - OldTime // Format should be - in minutes or seconds
```

also, how do I get the current time in the format `DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: What are `currentTime()` and `timeStoredInSharedPreference()`? Long, Date, ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two datetime formats in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216263/difference-between-two-datetime-formats-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8 you can calculate it with LocalDateTime and Duration

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime sixMinutesBehind = now.minusMinutes(6);

Duration duration = Duration.between(now, sixMinutesBehind);
long diff = Math.abs(duration.toMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

With **Java-9** onwards, you can use [`Duration#toMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutes--) and [`Duration#toSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toSeconds--). Note that `Duration#toMinutes` has been there since **Java-8** but `Duration#toSeconds` came with **Java-9**, and therefore you can use [`Duration#toMillis / 1000`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--) instead of `Duration#toSeconds` if you are using **Java-8**.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strOldDateTime = "24:7:2020 10:10:10";

        // Define the format
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d:M:yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        // Parse date-time as using the defined format
        LocalDateTime oldDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strOldDateTime, format);

        // Now
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

        Duration duration = Duration.between(oldDateTime, now);

        // Display the difference in minutes and seconds

        // ###########Java-8#############
        System.out.println(duration.toMinutes() + " minutes " + (duration.toMillis() / 1000) % 60);

        // ###########Java-9 onwards#############
        System.out.println(duration.toMinutes() + " minutes " + duration.toSeconds() % 60);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
106 minutes 17
106 minutes 17
```

Comment: On Java 8 you can use `Duration#getSeocnds` to get the same result as the one from `Duration#toSeconds` from Java 9. It was a bit confusing. In Java 9 they seem to have realized that they needed method named consistently with the other `toXxx` methods.

Comment: Thanks, Ole V. V. for the valuable input as usual.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    val oldTime = LocalDateTime.parse("24:07:2020 11:22:33", dateTimeFormatter)
    val newTime = LocalDateTime.parse("24:07:2020 11:32:33", dateTimeFormatter)

    Duration.between(oldTime, newTime).seconds shouldBe 10 * 60
}
```